# Re-direct a Mobile user

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

*** Update ***

I located and tried this script tag and it works perfectly, but how would I re-direct the user back to the main site.

```js
<script>if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
window.location ="http://www.soultrainradio.co.uk/mobile.html";}</script>
```

Kind regards

Good afternoon, I have a website and I want visitors to be re-directed to the JQuery site I created.
I found this code on YouTube, but this would not work...

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
if (screen.width <= 800){
 document.location = "http://soultrainradio.co.uk/mobile.html/"
}
</script>
```

I also tried...

```js
<script>if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){

window.location ="http://soultrainradio.co.uk/mobile.html.";}</script>
```

This did not work on a Android.

Would someone be able to guide me in what would be the correct JS code to re-direct.

Thanks
Gary

Comment: Your first one works for me, at least in a desktop browser. Are you sure your "screen.width" is indeed less than or equal to 800?  Did you test it via console.log(screen.width) before the "if" ?

Answer (score 0):

Use library [mobile-detect](http://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/), then you are sure that you will take all scenarios into account:

```html
<script src="http://rawgit.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js/master/mobile-detect.js"></script>
<script>
    var md = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);
    if (md.mobile()) {
        alert ("User is not a mobile device: " + md.Mobile());
    } else {
        alert ("User is on a desktop");   
    }
</script>
```

This way you have more options for checking if user is using mobile / tablet / desktop and get exact version and brand etc.

Comment: Keep in mind that while this is a super-easy approach, even the author of this library states that user-agent based detection is not a reliable solution, that the rules are constantly out-of-date, and the detection code has to be constantly updated (read the Warning portion on the library's website). Generally, it works pretty well though, so if you're not concerned that some people may get redirected to the wrong page, no worries. I change my user-agent string quite often ;)